# How to get current gps location both online or offline in android?

Tags: android, gps, location

I want to get the current location working with both online or offline GPS as well the expected behavior of the GPS is:
1. If wifi or 3g networks are available, it will use those to fetch the GPS position.
2. If NO wifi or 3g networks are avaiable it will use the OFFLINE GPS of the tablet (if present)
3. If nothing is present, it will display the Error message.

I am trying a lot but not succeeded yet. I am getting network enabled always true.

```
public boolean isGPSEnabled() {
        Location location = null;
        try {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = mLocationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            toast("Exception " + e.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }
```

If any one have idea. Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a single function split it into two functions to check which one is enabled

ie

To check if GPS enabled

```
public boolean isGPSEnabled() {
    Location location = null;
    try {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        toast("Exception " + e.toString());
    }
    return true;
}
```

To check if WIFI enabled

```
public boolean isWIFIEnabled() {
    Location location = null;
    try {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        toast("Exception " + e.toString());
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then whenever you want to check it,try this

```
if(isWIFIEnabled())
{
    //request location updates from network provider
}
else if(isGPSEnabled())
{
    //request location updates from gps provider    
}
else
{
    //display error
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply.But issue is that isGPSEnabled is always return true even if gps is off.

Comment: then i think you'll have to use broadcast receiver to check if GPS is getting fixed..

Comment: Is there any link. I am not having the exact idea. How to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for response. Didn't solved.Everytime getting wifi enabled true. May be device problem. SO, Will test in another device.

Comment: yes...may be problem with your device...and pls do update me.. @jagdish